# Jquery get values of all checked rows in table gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a table like below

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr><th>checked</th><th>id</th><th>text</th></tr>
<tr><td><input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="checker1"/></td><td>123</td><td>abc</td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="checker1"/></td><td>456</td><td>def</td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="checker1"/></td><td>789</td><td>ghi</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to retrieve (using jquery) a javascript array of all checked ID's in the table.

So far I have the following jquery code which on the click of the jqcc button brings me an alert box for each of the checked items, so instead of alert, i need to retrieve the value of the second td and add it to an array,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tableControl= document.getElementById('mytable');
    $('#jqcc').click(function() {
        $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).each(function() {
            alert('checked');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tableControl= document.getElementById('mytable');
   var arrayOfValues = [];
    $('#jqcc').click(function() {
        $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).each(function() {
            arrayOfValues.push($(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').text());
        }).get();
    });
});
```

`arrayOfValues` will hold the text inside the last td.

EDIT of course you could also use map

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tableControl= document.getElementById('mytable');
   var arrayOfValues = [];
    $('#jqcc').click(function() {
          arrayOfValues =  $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).map(function() {
            return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').text();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess this will add the last td element to the array ?? In actual fact there are other rows after the last td element, so this will not work. Will update the question. Thanks.

Comment: You need a `.get()` at the end of your `.map()` function.

Comment: @generalexception this will create an array with the text inside the last `<td>`, you can change the function to get a different td by using a class instead of `td:last`

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti my td doesent have a class. I need the value of the third TD along.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yep, forgot that in the hurry of writing, thanks! :)

Comment: @generalexception to get the third td use `find('td:eq(2)')` look here http://jsfiddle.net/n84U8/

Comment: Done it by replacing $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').text(); with $(this).parent().next().next().text();

Comment: @generalexception that works but is usually better to use closest and the use an eq() because it's more readable

Answer (score 5):

> I want to retrieve (using jquery) a javascript array of all checked ID's in the table.

Try:

```
var ids = $("#mytable tr:has(input:checked)").map(function() {
   var $tr = $(this);
   var id = $tr.find("td:last").text();
   return id;
}).toArray();

alert(ids.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var tableControl = document.getElementById('mytable');
$('#jqcc').click(function() {
    var result = []
    $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).each(function() {
        result.push($(this).parent().next().text());
    });
    alert(result);
});
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CwPCs/)

Answer (score 2):

First of all add the `id` as the value parameter of the `checkbox` as an input without a value is of little real use:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr><th>checked</th><th>id</th></tr>
    <tr><td><input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="checker1" value="123" /></td><td>123</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="checker1" value="456" /></td><td>456</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="checker1" value="789" /></td><td>789</td></tr>
</table>
```

Then in jQuery, create your array:

```
var checkedValues = $("input:checkbox:checked", "#mytable").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
alert(checkedValues.join(','));
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Swfq/)

Answer (score 0):

This does what you ask for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tableControl= document.getElementById('mytable');
    $('#jqcc').click(function() {
        var obj = new Array();
        $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).each(function() {
            var innertext = $(this).parent().next().text();
            obj.push(innertext);
        });
            console.debug(obj); // Write it to the console
    });
});
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/uEr3n/